# Suppose I try to convert a set to a list in python, why does 'generator object not callable' appear

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list `l` that contains `[1,2,5,4,3,6,6]`.

I run a `set(l)`, and I want to get the second largest in the sequence, so I wish to use something like `list(set(l)).sort()[-2]`. But when I try this, I get a message saying "generator object not callable".

Comment: I have a feeling that you have used `set` as a variable name somewhere in your code

Comment: What you did is wrong but that's not the error you were supposed to get. You should have gotten something about `Nonetype`. Try: `sorted(list(set(l)))[-2]`. Also, make sure you don't have a `generator` object named `set` somewhere.

Comment: `list` may also have been redefined.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the high possibility of you having redefined either `list` or `set`, 
the ist mehtod `sort` does the sorting inplace, and returns None - so you would get a

> 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

error as soon as you got the rest working.

So, starting from a clean Python session:

```
a = [5,7, 9, 10, 2, 3, 10]
b = set(a)
print(sorted(list(b))[-2])
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, list/set was redefined earlier and hence the error.
I ran the following code in a new instance of python console,

```
n = int(input())
l=[int(input()) for _ in range(n)]
print(sorted(list(set(l)))[-2])
```

Suppose the input is `[1,2,5,4,3,6,6]`, code runs a set on the sequence and then proceeds to convert it to a list after which indexing is possible